# Why is the Power BI Paginated Report Viewer caching results on page two?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Power Bi Report that uses the Paginated Reports viewer.  I have filters (Slicer) that change the parameters for the report and it'll update.  The strange behaviour is that it'll only update page one and three.  Page two will cache.  So I'll get results like this and it confuses the users (and me).

Any ideas on why it's only caching page 2?

**Page 1**
[image: Page 1]

**Page 2 (See time, selected locations, and page numbering)**
[image: Cached Page]